# EF Core Many To Many with owning relationship that has one

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Given the following three tables what is the best way to set up the classes on the C# side along with the needed fluent configuration?

| Character | Character_Abilities | Ability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Id | Id |
| Name | CharacterId | Name |
| Abilities | AbilityId |  |

For the sake of matching my need, I will never need to get the characters by ability. Only character to abilities.

In my thinking I need to have three classes (only cause of the id on the lookup table)

abilities can be added by anyone, but no one owns them. When a character is deleted it should clean up the references in the lookup table but not delete any of it's referenced abilities. abilities can be used by any character.

I would think I need

```
internal class Character
{
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
 
        public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        public virtual ICollection<Character_Abilities> Character_Abilities{ get; set; } = new List<Character_Abilities>();
}

internal class Character_Abilities
{
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Guid CharacterId {get;set;) = default!;

        public virtual int AbilityId { get; set; } = default!;
}

internal class Ability
{
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

With a Fluent Config like

```
public DbSet<Character> Characters { get; set; } = default!;

public DbSet<Ability> Abilities { get; set; } = default!;


protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Character>(character=>
            {
            character.OwnsMany(
                t => t.AbilitiesLookup,
                char_abil=>
                {
                    char_abil.HasOne<Ability>();
                });
            });
```

it makes sense to me as an owns many and a has one relationship as I only want to go one way. but how do I specify the entity for the middle table in the owning side? maybe I'm overthinking the relationship table. What am I missing?

In a perfect world my Character class should contain a list of Abilities; no reference to the lookup table.

Comment: Why `OwnsMany`? Why not just `HasMany`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Answer (score 1):

Note that surrogate id is not actually required for join table and if you are not going to expose it as a separate table (i.e. `public DbSet<CharacterAbility> Characters => Set<CharacterAbility>()`) you can just rely [on conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) to generate the table for "fully defined relationship":

```cs
public class Character
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
 
    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public virtual ICollection<Ability> Abilities { get; set; } = new List<Ability>();
}


public class Ability
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public virtual ICollection<Character> Characters { get; set; } = new List<Character>();
}
```

If you want to specify the table name then you can use the fluent API to [configure it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#join-entity-type-configuration):

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Character>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Abilities)
    .WithMany(p => p.Character)
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("Character_Abilities"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think I have been overthinking the problem. Your answer is correct and would work but what I was looking for was a unidirectional binding. I had to find the correct search phrase in my googling to get the right answer. According to this discussion it is something that people have asked for, there has been some work done to move that way, but it is not yet ready. 

Here is the article. https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/3864